# Overloading functions, which have format and params args, with new string argument

Tags: c#, overloading, parameters

I have such a function and its overload:

1. `SomeMethod(String format, params Object[] prms)`
2. `SomeMethod(String str, Exception ex, String format, params Object[] prms)`

The problem is that when I use second variant of the signature my application decides to go through the first and uses "str" as format. Can I somehow avoid this without changing params array type (in my situation I have no opportunity to do it)?

Comment: How exactly are you calling it?  I haven't been able to reproduce.

Comment: Could you show how do you call the second method? I have tried to create a prototype of this, and when I call the second method, it invokes only the second method.

Comment: @juharr is it even possible that calling a method with 4 parameters to invoke it's overload instead with only 2 parameters? I don't think so... not in C#

Comment: @meJustAndrew It is when the second one has the `params` modifier and is an array of `object`.  Try calling it with `SomeMethod("", 1, 2, 3);`

Comment: In fact as long as the second parameter is convertible to `Exception` and the 3rd to `string` the second overload will be chosen over the first.

Comment: @juharr thank you! didn't even noticed the keyword.

Comment: what version of c# are you using?  you can always force this by doing `SomeMethod(str:"", ...)` and `SomeMethod(format:"", ...)`

Comment: Well, I use this overload for error logging purpoises. The first variant is used for non-exceptional type of error (such as incorrect work) and the second is used for logging exceptions. And i do use Exception type as a second parameter when a call second overload. 

@Matthew Whited What jou suggested seems to be a solution but it underlines parameters name with the red line and shows a tooltip: "Named parameters cannot precede positional"

Comment: @juharr But that is my problem that virtually my situation is opposite to what you said

Comment: @MatthewWhited however, you're right. i named each parameter and this worked. Not as convinient as I wanted but anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking you could get away with just the first parameter but I guess the compiler requires you to name everything after the first one you name... it might work better to just give the two methods different names since they are doing different things anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if parameter two is of type `Exception` then second overload is preferred as conversion `Exception -> Exception` is better than `Exception -> Object`. @MatthewWhited noted that you can pass in named parameters to force one or the other overload to be called.

> 7.5.3.2 Better function member
>   C# 4 specificatipn
>
> For the purposes of determining the better function member, a stripped-down argument list A is constructed containing just the argument expressions themselves in the order they appear in the original argument list.
>   Parameter lists for each of the candidate function members are constructed in the following way:
>   •  The expanded form is used if the function member was applicable only in the expanded form.
>   •  Optional parameters with no corresponding arguments are removed from the parameter list
>   •  The parameters are reordered so that they occur at the same position as the corresponding argument in the argument list.
>   Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions { E1, E2, ..., EN } and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types { P1, P2, ..., PN } and { Q1, Q2, ..., QN }, MP is defined to be a better function member than MQ if
>   •  for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is not better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX, and
>   •  for at least one argument, the conversion from EX to PX is better than the conversion from EX to QX.

The following code calls method #1, #1, #1, #2, #2

```
public class test_params
{
    public void SomeMethod(String format, params Object[] prms) { Console.Write("#1: ");  Console.WriteLine(format, prms); }
    public void SomeMethod(String str, Exception ex, String format, params Object[] prms) { Console.Write("#2 "); Console.WriteLine("str={0} Excep={1}", str, ex.Message); Console.WriteLine(format, prms); }
    public void Test()
    {
        SomeMethod("", 1, 2, 3);                                            // #1:
        SomeMethod("{0} {1}", 1, 2);                                        // #1: 1 2
        SomeMethod("{0} {1}", 1, "p2", 3, 4);                               // #1: 1 p2
        SomeMethod("{0} {1}", new Exception("Test excep"), "p2");           // #2 str={0} {1} Excep=Test excep // p2
        SomeMethod("Str1", new Exception("Test excep"), "{0} {1}", 1, 2);   // #2 str=Str1 Excep=Test excep // 1 2
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note if you call `SomeMethod("", new Exception())` it should resolve to #1 and not #2.

Comment: True, with no third parameter it can't match second overload. I'm interested in why the OP is seeing different behaviour. The basic function matching rules were similar as far back as Visual Studio .Net 2003. It would be good to know the details of corner cases where an unexpected overload is matched.

Comment: Maybe he was using a mono compiler or something.  They do have know issues out of compliance with the c# spec.